# Unable to import scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, python-attrs

I was trying to import scrapy in python 3.7, and got this error:

```
import scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\response.py", line 10, in <module>
    from twisted.web import http
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 102, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import interfaces, protocol, address
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\address.py", line 101, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=False, repr=False, eq=False)
TypeError: attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eq'
```

I've updated the attrs as well using "pip install --upgrade attrs"
but still getting the same.

Answer (score 2):

If `pip install --upgrade attrs` doesn't fix it, the pip command probably points to the wrong pip. Try `python3 -m pip install --upgrade attrs`.  Also compare the output of `pip list` and `python3 -m pip list`.

Comment: Yes this fixed it, I did got a warning for the same when installing sracpy.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by installing the wheel library and twisted first prior to installing the scrapy that worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to execute scrapy in command prompt, I was getting following error:

```
C:\Users\XXXXX>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\response.py", line 10, in <module>
    from twisted.web import http
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 102, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import interfaces, protocol, address
  File "c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\address.py", line 101, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=False, repr=False, eq=False)
TypeError: attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eq'
```

I tried to check the versions and tried to update them too

Short Output from pip list

```
C:\Users\XXXXX>pip list
attr                               0.3.1
attrs                              19.1.0
Scrapy                             2.1.0

C:\Users\XXXXX>pip install --upgrade attrs
Collecting attrs
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/db/4313ab3be961f7a763066401fb77f7748373b6094076ae2bda2806988af6/attrs-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: attrs
  Found existing installation: attrs 19.1.0
    Uninstalling attrs-19.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled attrs-19.1.0
Successfully installed attrs-19.3.0

C:\Users\XXXXX>pip install --upgrade scrapy
Requirement already up-to-date: scrapy in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: w3lib>=1.17.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protego>=0.1.15 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (0.1.16)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: queuelib>=1.4.2 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Twisted>=17.9.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: parsel>=1.5.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cryptography>=2.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyOpenSSL>=16.2.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: lxml>=3.5.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: service-identity>=16.0.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zope.interface>=4.1.3 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cssselect>=0.9.1 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from w3lib>=1.17.0->scrapy) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: PyHamcrest!=1.10.0,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: attrs>=19.2.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (20.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.1.3->scrapy) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna>=2.5 in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycparser in c:\users\XXXXX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (2.19)

C:\Users\XXXXX>python --version
Python 3.7.3

C:\Users\XXXXX>scrapy
Scrapy 2.1.0 - no active project

Usage:
  scrapy <command> [options] [args]

Available commands:
  bench         Run quick benchmark test
  fetch         Fetch a URL using the Scrapy downloader
  genspider     Generate new spider using pre-defined templates
  runspider     Run a self-contained spider (without creating a project)
  settings      Get settings values
  shell         Interactive scraping console
  startproject  Create new project
  version       Print Scrapy version
  view          Open URL in browser, as seen by Scrapy

  [ more ]      More commands available when run from project directory

Use "scrapy <command> -h" to see more info about a command

C:\Users\XXXXX>
```

As you can see, attrs version was messing up with scrapy.

Answer (score -1):

use `pip3 install scrapy` as it will install for python3 , otherwise if you have python2 installed `pip install scrapy` installs for python2.

Comment: It did not work. But thanks a lot for your response.